# RTSP live streaming on Samsung Tizen TV

Tags: streaming, rtsp, toast, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I am building a TV app with Samsung TOAST and Caph based on angularJS1.

My app is calling our server API to get the list of products.
Once a product is selected, a request is sent with the product's url which has the following format:

```
    <ourServer>//play?url=rtsp%3A%2F%2F<IPAddress>%3A8554%2F<streamID>&mouse=abs
```

This launches an exe on the  server which gets the streamed video via the RTSP url.
Video is encoded with h.264.

This is working fine in Chrome browser, with the exe and the product's video opening in new windows.
But, on Samsung Tizen TV, it cannot work since RTSP is not supported.

Is there any way of making it possible to keep the product's url as is and handle RTSP in Samsung Smart TV (any extra-plugin, workaround, ...)?
For example [Tizen Player](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.2/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__MEDIA__PLAYER__MODULE.html) seems to handle RTSP but how should I use it?

Or are we gonna have to change the code on server side to use for example webRTC instead of RTSP?

Thanks in advance